# There is no any line related the error but it says critical error

Tags: debug, wp-debug

My website says critical error on website after add my custom code but there is no any line related my custom code in log file.There are only 2 repater lines and they are standard for my website, not big problems.

also Wordpress doesn't show error message on browser except "critical error...".

how can I detect the code problem?

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Why not show the problem code also?

Comment: Does your server have a `wp-content/debug.log` file? Would that file be writable if it existed? Is the code in your question located in `wp-config.php`?

Comment: yes, the code in wp-config.php. debug.log files contains two repeater lines.one of them is related a mega menu plugin, other line is related max upload size limit setting.on every refresh page, the lines are added to the log file.but there is no related code with my custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following wp-config.php setup - note WP writes to the file wp-content/debug.log - this config also stops any errors from being rendered to the browser.

Note that setting the constant WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER to `true` enables you to disabled the default WP error screen.

```php
// Disable display of errors and warnings 
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );

define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', false );

// disable WP fail-safe screen ##
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
```

Comment: Have you high ranked users problem in recent days? yesterday, moderator Jacop did what you did with this your "answer".as you can see on my question, already I know that code and I tried and they don't work.so, why you write "answer" without read question? you are not new user?

Comment: If the answer does not help, no problem, someone else might try and help you - but please try to remember that this is all offered for free, with good intentions.

Comment: @Farukrıza be nice, Q Studio is just trying to help, and they're only ranked 229th :) They also have config defines your question does not have which might solve your question

Comment: That's right @TomJNowell, but I do have more gold stars than you ;) - sadly, neither stars nor ranking are real, nor keep you warm at night.. this is all just for the love of helping others...

Comment: I would have more gold badges but for the love of moderation. Bringing it back on topic, `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` is different here, perhaps edit and draw attention to it to explain what the answer changes

Comment: Seriously @TomJNowell - and I am well aware this off-topic - big respect for your commitment and dedication.. and patience.. you deserve all the gold stars you could ever dream of!

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you for your motivation on helping but also you must notice a thing that the answer doesn't help me and I don't want un-useful answers.I want to show technic error message on website or in log file but the code doesn't work.